# Run gtest/gmock on local directory

Tags: c++, static-libraries, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to install gtest/gmock on my local directory, not on /usr/lib, where static library usually resides.

I've already compiled libgmock.a  libgmock_main.a  libgtest.a  libgtest_main.a, and put them into my working directory, how to include the header file and Makefile?

Comment: What do you mean by "include the Makefile"? Do you intend to integrate this into the build system of your application? If so we would need to know a little more about your build system?

Comment: Does [this example from the Google Test documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#writing-the-main-function) help?

Comment: I'm doing a project with needs gtest/gmock. I want to install it on the dev branch and /hao directory, without affecting the outside world. The reason why it should be kept isolated is that in /jiang directory, which is parallel with /hao, already has a older version of gtest/gmock, which couldn't be accessed and used.
When I try to compile my test file, the compiler errors "gtest/gtest.h not found".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-I<path to gtest/gtest.h>` to your compiler call (e.g. `CXXFLAGS` environment variable). This directory is not in the system-wide include path so you have to specify it explicitly.

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is
#include <gtest/gtest.h> in my source code
Then my makefile is 

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread

export GTEST_HOME="googletest/googletest/include;googletest/googlemock/include"
export LIB_HOME="googletest/lib"

test: testfile.cpp
 $(CC) -o test_out -I $(GTEST_HOME) -L $(LIB_HOME) testfile.cpp $(CFLAGS)

For the current directory, under "googletest/googletest/include/gtest" there is gtest.h
And under "googletest/googletest/include/gmock.h"

But still get "gtest.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Note that you need to set `CXXFLAGS` rather than `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Well, I think CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS are just symbols, and will be replaced with the actual content?

Comment: BTW: It's often a good idea to edit your question to include the additional information. In contrast to comments multi-line code blocks are allowed there.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know how to format my makefile into code blocks

Comment: The [help page about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) might be useful.